# Cómo eliminar elementos vacíos de una matriz en java?

Tags: java, matriz

Tengo este programa ya hecho que es para una tarea que consiste en contar las palabras repetidas de una cadena y tengo que utilizar los métodos ya planteados, pero a la hora de visualizar las matrices finales quedan los valores repetidos por eso salen los 0 y null. En la clase `Coleccion` tengo una matriz para pasar cada palabra del main y otra matriz para guardar los elementos que no se repiten.

```
public class ContadorPalabras {

  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Digite una cadena (FINALIZAR CON ENTER)");
        String leer = Leer.dato();
        String[] cole = leer.split(" ");
        
        Coleccion pal = new Coleccion(cole.length);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < cole.length; i++) {
            if(pal.estaPalabra(cole[i]) == false){
                pal.insertaPalabra(cole[i]);
            }       
        }
        System.out.println("La cantidad de palabras repetidas son:");
         pal.Visualizar();
    }
    
}

public class Coleccion{

       String[] col;
       String[] coleccion;
       int[] con;
       int in =0, i=0;
       
    public  Coleccion(int val){
       col = new String[val];
       con = new int[val];
       coleccion = new String[val];
        
    }
    
    public boolean estaPalabra(String palabra){
       
        boolean ele = false;
        col[in] = palabra;
        
          for (int i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            if (col[in].equals(col[i]) && in !=i && col[i]!=null) {
                con[i]++;
                ele =true;
                break;
            }else
                ele = false;
        }
        in++;
        return ele;
    }
    public void insertaPalabra(String pala){ 
        coleccion[i] = pala;
        con[i] =1;
        i++;
        
    }
  
    public void Visualizar(){

         for (int j = 0; j < coleccion.length; j++) {
           System.out.print(coleccion[j]+" ");
         }
           System.out.println();
         for (int j = 0; j < con.length; j++) {
           System.out.print(con[j]+"    ");
         }
  }
    
}
```

Comment: Me gustaron los cambios que has hecho, si en el 1° for de Visualizar, pones el sout en un `if( coleccion[j] != null ) {`, y al 2° `if( con[j] != 0 ) {` tendrás el resultado buscado :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo!!

Comment: Un placer maestro!!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una nueva matriz y copiar los elementos que no sean nulos o vacíos a la nueva matriz.

Un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo en el método Visualizar de la clase `Coleccion`:

```
public void Visualizar() {
    // Eliminar elementos vacíos de la matriz coleccion
    String[] coleccionSinNulos = new String[coleccion.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < coleccion.length; j++) {
        if (coleccion[j] != null && !coleccion[j].isEmpty()) {
            coleccionSinNulos[index] = coleccion[j];
            index++;
        }
    }

    // Eliminar elementos vacíos de la matriz con
    int[] conSinNulos = new int[con.length];
    index = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < con.length; j++) {
        if (coleccion[j] != null && !coleccion[j].isEmpty()) {
            conSinNulos[index] = con[j];
            index++;
        }
    }

    // Visualizar las matrices sin elementos vacíos
    for (int j = 0; j < coleccionSinNulos.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(coleccionSinNulos[j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int j = 0; j < conSinNulos.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(conSinNulos[j] + "    ");
    }
}
```

Creamos dos nuevas matrices `coleccionSinNulos` y `conSinNulos` para almacenar los elementos que no son nulos o vacíos. Luego, se recorre la matriz original `coleccion` y se copian los elementos que no son nulos o vacíos a la nueva matriz `coleccionSinNulos`, y lo mismo se hace con la matriz con.

Finalmente, se recorre y visualiza las matrices sin elementos vacíos.

Comment: Que extraño, copie la correción, lo corrí y hizo lo mismo que sin la correción.